# Intellij Main Menu positioning

Tags: intellij-idea, xfce

Some world first problems right here.. Any idea if and how can i position Main Menu, so it appears on right side?

[image]

I assume, Intellij uses desktop environment settings to render a mac-like global menu ( running xfce ), but I do not want to change my system settings, just override Intellij behaviour.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA does not have any settings to change the native behaviour of Linux's main menu. If possible, it can only be changed by means of the OS itself.

Comment: @Andrey its not linux menu, its Intellij menu, I just assume its generated using desktop environment settings ( but this assumption is not important at all  )